# Can not enter course code into timetable, timetable is returning empty

Tags: python, html, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating a new system for a college timetable, I am looking for free slots in a timetable(where the student has no lectures). I need to enter the course code because at the moment it is opening up a blank timetable, So I need to be able to enter a course code in (e.g CASE2)

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window() #opens up website, probably not needed. 

driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.get('https://opentimetable.dcu.ie/')
df2=pd.read_html(driver.find_element_by_id("week-pdf-content").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0] 
# currently not searching for anything.

print(df2)
```

Comment: first check what you get with `find_element_by_id(...).get_attribute(...)`. Second: check if it  uses real table in HTML `<table>` `<tr>` `<td>` because `read_html()` can get data only from standard `<table>` - it can't get data if it use `<div>`, etc to simulate table.

Comment: I checked this page and at start it display empty table. It needs to select `CASE2` on left side (in `Search`) to get data in table. I don't see you try to select `CASE2`. What is your problem? You didn't describe it.

Comment: Yes I'm wondering where do I tell my code to enter a course code

Comment: it seems obvious: after `get(..)`,  before `find_element_by_id(...).get_attribute(...)`. And you have to: use function to select list, `.click()` it to open list, select `Programmes of study`, select field `Search`, `send_key("CASE2")`, select `[ ] CASE2` on list below, click `[ ]` to check it. So you have to do the same as real human.

Comment: you could add `import` to code in question so we could simply copy it to run it and test ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code has to behave like real human.

So you have to

- select dropdown menu and `.click()` it to open list and next select option `Programmes of study`, or use special class `Select()` for this,
- select field `Search` and `.send_key("CASE2")`,
- select checkbox `[ ] CASE2` on list below and `.click()` it.

Tested on `Firefox` and `Chrome` on Linux.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

import pandas as pd
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.get('https://opentimetable.dcu.ie/')

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("select"))
select.select_by_visible_text('Programmes of Study')

search = driver.find_element_by_id("textSearch")
search.send_keys("CASE2")

#checkbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@type="checkbox"]')  # can find wrong `checkbox` - it would need `time.sleep` until it removes other `checkboxes` 
checkbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[following-sibling::div[contains(text(), "CASE2")]]')  # it works but it is harder to remeber
#checkbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(text(), "CASE2")]')  # it works (in this HTML) and it is simpler to remeber
checkbox.click()

time.sleep(3)  #  JavaScript needs time to replace data in table

html = driver.find_element_by_id("week-pdf-content").get_attribute('outerHTML')
df2 = pd.read_html(html)[0] 

print(df2.to_string()) # to_string() to display all columns without `...`
```